# React.js won't load a local file, passin background image style attribute as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to pass `style` attribute as a prop when rendering a component I've made. When I pass a local image as `background:`  it won't load, but if it is an image address it loads as it should. [Here is the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqB1v.png).

Here is the how I'm passing the prop:

```css
      <Key
        style={{
          background: require("./keyImages/0.jpeg"),
          backgroundSize: "70px",
        }}
      />
```

Thanks a lot in advance for help!

Comment: Try using url intead of require.

Comment: How require/import works for images depends completely on the bundler you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import imgUrl from "./keyImages/0.jpeg";

      <Key
        style={{
          backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
          backgroundSize: "70px",
        }}
      />
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot! However is it possible to use `require()` instead of import? I might need to do this in the middle of a function, and import only allows at the top part.

Edit: Just tested, and yes it works.

Comment: You can try to use dynamic import but there are some things to keep in mind with it: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import, https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import